# How to get Purview GUID from Office365 Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-purview

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to process a bunch of files and emails from Office365 (OneDrive, Sharepoint, Exchange Online).

This works well, fetching the OneDrive records via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{dir_id}/children`. No problem there.

But now I need to assign a Purview label to some of these items using the Purview API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/add-label?tabs=HTTP

All the Purview API documentation talks about "*`guid` – The globally unique identifier of the entity*" as input, to specify which document I want to assign the label to. How do I get that guid?

I don't see any "guid" attribute in my OneDrive responses. To be honest I got completely lost in the infinite indirections and IDs of the Microsoft API.

How do Graph API responses relate to Purview GUIDs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it's the same, but the Graph API beta allows you to [set retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-setretentionlabel?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) label on `driveItem`

```
PATCH beta/drives/{drive-id}/items/{id}/retentionLabel
```

Probably, you don't need to call Purview API.

If you want apply a label using Purview API, parse GUID from `eTag` property of the `driveItem`.

Resource:

[Apply retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/auto-apply-retention-labels-scenario)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't look like the same API / concept.

Comment: @user124114 If you need to set retention label in Purview API then parse the guid from the etag property of the driveItem